# jest-mock-extended trying to return promise value

Tags: jestjs

I'm using jest-mock-extended and i'm trying to mock out a public function on a class interface thats been mocked.

Here is my IApiService

```
export default interface IApiService {
  send: (url: string) => Promise<any>;
}
```

My Test for homeService class which has only one public function called start.

```
import { mock } from "jest-mock-extended";
import HomeService from "./homeService";
import IApiService from "../Api/interface";

describe("HomeService", () => {
  let apiService: IApiService;
  let service: HomeService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    apiService = mock<IApiService>();
    service = new HomeService(apiService);
  });

  it("Should shit all over the place", () => {
    const mock_fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve("response"));
    apiService.send.mockReturnValue(mock_fetch);
    service.start();
    expect(mock_fetch).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

I'm trying to get **send** method to return a mocked value but none of the functions on mock seem to work the way I'm trying to call them.

Comment: You're making `send` function to return a function, which never be called if it's not intended to be. Likely should be `apiService.send.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve("response"))`

Comment: Can you give me an example ? send function is a return function ? I updated my code example to show my send method in the service. When I try to use mockReturnValue I get this error: Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type '(url: string) => Promise<any>'.

Comment: I don't use this library and cannot provide a workable example. It should likely be exactly what you posted, with the fix that was suggested above. In case there's type problem (it was there at the time of posting but not mentioned), `apiService` needs to be typed correctly because currently it's not typed as Jest spy. From what I see here https://github.com/marchaos/jest-mock-extended#assigning-mocks-with-a-type , it should be `let apiService: MockProxy<IApiService>`.

Comment: Thanks Estus I tried the fix you suggested but it always says property mockReturnValue does not exist on type ..... Also not seeing where send is returning a function when its just returning a promise.

Comment: But the error should have been before that because you already used mockReturnValue, right? From what I see, MockProxy type should be enough to fix this. If it's still doesn't fix this, please, provide your current attempt and exact error message.

Comment: MockProxy did work but not sure why even after reading their docs explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Since Jest spy API is used on mocked object, it should be properly typed, as suggested in [the documentation](https://github.com/marchaos/jest-mock-extended#assigning-mocks-with-a-type):

```
let apiService: MockProxy<IApiService>;
```

This merges method types with Jest spy types, `send` type is something like:

```
((url: string) => Promise<any>) & jest.SpyInstance<Promise<any>>
```

Mocked function is expected to return a promise, not a function that returns a promise, so it should be mocked as:

```
apiService.send.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve("response"))
```

or

```
apiService.send.mockResolvedValue("response")
```